# angular material io MatDatePicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am new to Angular/Angular Material.

I have a div with 2 MatDatePicker input fields:

```
<div class="docs-example-viewer-body">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Employee" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployeeId" name="employee_name" (ngModelChange)="setSelectedEmployee($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]="employee.id">
        {{employee.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a start date" [(ngModel)]="inputStartDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker [startAt]="startDate"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose an end date" [(ngModel)]="inputEndDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker [startAt]="endDate"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>


  <p *ngIf="selectedEmployeeId"> Selected value: {{selectedEmployeeId}} from {{inputStartDate}} until {{inputEndDate}}</p>
</div>
```

But I get the following error in the browser:

> MatDatepicker can only be associated with a single input. at
>   MatDatepicker._registerInput (datepicker.es5.js:1281)
>       at MatDatepickerInput.registerDatepicker (datepicker.es5.js:1560)

Thanks for your solutions or feedback

Joost

Comment: Yay, I just made this mistake. `picker` needs to be unique between the two, try `[matDatepicker]="picker1"` and `[matDatepicker]="picker2"` or similar, so long as they're unique. The `[for]` binding will also need to match the new id.

Answer (score 20):

The instance variable name needs to be unique to each instance. In the example, I've used `picker1` and `picker2` but feel free to use better names. [Here's a sample from the Material plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/oby9dwhvzvQoweQCQKqN?p=preview)

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Choose a start date" [(ngModel)]="inputStartDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1 [startAt]="startDate"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="Choose an end date" [(ngModel)]="inputEndDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker2 [startAt]="endDate"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```